# Problema al ejecutar Python Selenium, Abre la pagina en el mismo navegador y no carga la pagina

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Tengo un codigo que ya funciona dentro de otras computadoras pero en la de mi trabajo no permite ejecutarlo, aparece este error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el programa se cae, estoy usando este codigo

```
introducir import os
import time
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from io import BytesIO
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
#path de Download
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads")

fecha_actual = dt.date.today()
# Instalar el browser de Chrome

#path de Download
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads")
# Instalar el browser de Chrome
#pathChrom= os.path.expanduser('~')+'\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\nuevo'
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

options_cs = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options_cs.add_argument('--headless')
#options_cs.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={pathChrom}')
options_cs.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options_cs.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ""Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36")
options_cs.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options_cs.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options_cs.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options_cs.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options_cs.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options_cs.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options_cs.add_argument('--print-to-pdf')  # Habilitar la impresión a PDF
options_cs.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options_cs.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options_cs.add_argument('--enable-print-browser')
options_cs.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

browserOrion = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=options_cs)
browserOrion.maximize_window()
url = 'https://sbp0100tcm14.pacifico.bpgf/orion/netperfmon/events.aspx'
browserOrion.get(url)
main_window = browserOrion.current_window_handle
time.sleep(15)
```

Al momento que se ejecuta aparece este problema
File "C:\Users\nechever\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\nechever\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Entonces no avanza el programa, no se si sea problemas de instalacion, o necesite alguna dependencia mas, si son permisos de usuario o editar las variables del sistema, Lo cual si tengo en el path la direccion ..\python\scripts

Quisiera saber como lo soliciono no es problema de codigo sino de configuracion.

Comment: Revisa la importación del driver que tienes aquí y que sea la última versión del .exe
---------------
 browserOrion = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=options_cs)